# Memory problem in R "Error:cannot allocate vector of size 344 kb"

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, memory-management

My `memory.limit()` is 3583,I have a 64-bit machine with 8G RAM at home,and just remote access to my computer in the office then found it was also 8G RAM.So
I can't run the R codes below successfully,should I reset the memory limit?But someone thinks it's a dangerous approach, could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?  Thanks in advance!

```
loop<-1000;T<-45
bbb<-list()
for(i in 1:loop)
{
  bbb[[i]]<-list()
  bbb[[i]][[1]]<-matrix(rep(1,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[2]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1) 
  bbb[[i]][[3]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1) 
  bbb[[i]][[4]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1) 
  bbb[[i]][[5]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[6]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[7]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1) 
  bbb[[i]][[8]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[9]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[10]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[11]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[12]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[13]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[14]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[15]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[16]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[17]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[18]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[19]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[20]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[21]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[22]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[23]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[24]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[25]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[26]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[27]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[28]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[29]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[30]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[31]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[32]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
  bbb[[i]][[33]]<-matrix(rep(0,loop*(T-1)),loop,T-1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends what you doing with the matrix list, but maybe you could break your task into smaller chunks? Or you can try using `lapply`, which runs much faster on my machine but ultimately creates an object of exactly the same size. I *think* `lapply` has some memory saving advantages when repeating data.

If this doesn't work, try looking into the `Matrix` package and sparse matrices.

```
create_bbb <- function(loop = 1000, T = 45){

  inner.list <- lapply(1:33, FUN = function(x){

    if(x == 1) fill <- 1
    else fill <- 0

    return(matrix(rep(fill, loop * (T-1)), loop, T-1))

  })

  bbb <- lapply(1:loop, function(.) inner.list)

  return(bbb)
}


bbb_test <- create_bbb()

# Check
all.equal(bbb, bbb_test)
# TRUE
```

Comment: Did it work on your machine then? I think this is the best review of memory usage I found [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html). It states "a subtlety of the size of an object is that components can be shared across multiple objects" which is my best guess as to why `lapply` would help here

Comment: Yes, it really works! Lapply is better than for-loops. Thanks again!